# How do I size fuses to handle sudden changes in AC line voltage into a capacitive load?

Tags: current, rectifier, math, fuses

Suppose I have a rectifier on the AC line, followed by some caps and a load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4EXVG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the AC line is suddenly increased, there's a current surge into the capacitor. This can happen when power is applied, during a line surge, or when recovering from a line dip. A precharge circuit can help with power application, but it's less helpful after a dip.

The only things limiting this current surge are the impedance of the circuit components and lanes, ESR of the cap, and inductance of the AC line. The line inductance looks like it should dominate. So there's an LDC circuit between the line inductance and the cap. It's like a tank circuit, except it looks like you'll only get one pulse out of it instead of a decaying ring wave. But there, I'm stuck.

How do I compute the peak and width of the current pulse into the caps, so as to size my fuses appropriately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first approximation for the fuse size is to make sure the steady-state current draw is not greater than the maximum no-blow current for the fuse.

The next step is to ensure that it is sized to protect against fire / explosion if there's a hard abnormal in the circuit. For example, a safety test for your product would be to short out the capacitor after the bridge and apply the maximum specified AC input. The fuse should blow without the diodes burning / rupturing / emitting smoke or debris.

Once your fuse is appropriate from these perspectives, you can do your line drop tests and see how well the fuse performs. If you find nuisance blows, bear in mind that if you increase the rating or decrease the response time (go from fast to slow-blow, for instance) you'll need to repeat your safety test to make sure it's still appropriate from a safety perspective, and may need to beef up other components in the circuit to make sure the fuse blows first.

Answer (score 2):

The usual solution to this is to use a slow-blow fuse. These blow only if excess current is maintained for a relatively long time. The datasheet will provide more quantitative descriptions of "excess current" and "long time".

As far as computing the peak current of the inrush current, it's probably easiest to measure. Connecting an ideal voltage source to an ideal capacitor results in an infinite current. In reality, neither the voltage source (the device's power supply) or the capacitors or the wires connecting them are ideal, so the inrush current is determined by the non-ideal inductance and resistance of all these components.

The duration of the inrush period can be calculated if you've measured the resistance, and know the capacitance. Multiply the resistance and the capacitance together, and this is the time it will take to charge the capacitor about 63% of the way to its final value. Research [RC time constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_time_constant) for more detail.

Another option is to deliberately introduce a series component to limit inrush current. This can be a resistor at simplest, but a more sophisticated and efficient device is a NTC thermistor. By deliberately selecting your current limiting device (rather than relying on wire resistance and such), calculating the inrush current, and thus sizing the fuses, is much easier. Wikipedia has more detail under [inrush current limiter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inrush_current_limiter).

Answer (score 0):

Not only fuse should be rate, but switch as well.
a) Fuse rating

[image]

where

[image]

you need just one slo-blo fuse at maximum voltage 230V (RMS)

b) Switch

[image]

at maximum voltage 2x230V (RMS) or more

FL: Fool load
NL: No Load

Comment: Those aliased fonts make me want to gouge my eyes. Maybe you could replace them with LaTeX markup, which would be readable?

Comment: Now I hope it is readable. This is produced by Word Equation Editor and it is a bit more than Bob Pease used! I'm not aware about LaTeX. In any case my answer refered to a circuit with transformer.

Comment: See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/73169/how-to-get-high-current-from-9-volt-batteries/73194#73194 for an example of LaTeX markup (hit the edit button to see the source). Searching for "latex" and "mathjax" will find complete references on the intertube.